# Pandas installed but No module named 'pandas' in jupyter notebook? (Mac)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I've installed pandas but still couldn't import pandas in Jupyter

```
(base) ch@Ch-MacBookPro ~ % pip3 show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.4.3
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: The Pandas Development Team
Author-email: pandas-dev@python.org
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /Users/ch/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: numpy, python-dateutil, pytz
Required-by: datashader, holoviews, hvplot, seaborn, statsmodels, xarray


(base) ch@Ch-MacBookPro ~ % which python
/Users/ch/opt/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

Comment: Which environment is Jupyter running in?

Comment: this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@shivangisareen/for-anyone-using-jupyter-notebook-installing-packages-18a9468d0c1c) might help

Comment: Need to tell how are you running jupyter

Comment: running jupyter through Anaconda

Comment: I did pip3 install pandas

Answer (score 0):

I believe that depends on which python you are using in your jupyter notebook. A short and quick way is to type `!pip install pandas` within the notebook cell, which should install a pandas package in the python used by your jupyter notebook.

Comment: @Neo_Mok, please don't suggest outdated practices. In modern Jupyter (not Colab), it should be `%pip install` as the command for running a pip install inside notebook cells. The exclamation point in conjunction with install commands can cause issues & so the magic `%pip install` and `%conda install` commands were added to insure installation occurs in the environment being used by the kernel underlying the notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic install command. ...

Comment: <continued> See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more on why to avoid exclamation point with install commands when running inside a cell in modern Jupyter and use the magics that are current best practice.